# Specify locale id in url

Tags: angularjs

I can find very little about this specific subject of angularJS.

How can I specify and rewrite all urls with a locale id, like `en-uk`, `nl-nl`?

I also want to use proper routing to automate the process and providing the locale id to the corresponding controllers.

A few examples:

- /#!/en-uk/home ---> Use of controller `Home` and provide the locale id `en-uk`
- /#!/nl-nl/home ---> Use of controller `Home` and provide the locale id `nl-nl`
- /#!/en-uk/shop ---> Use of controller `Shop` and provide the locale id `en-uk`
- /#!/nl-nl/shop ---> Use of controller `Shop` and provide the locale id `nl-nl`

**Question:** How is this done in angularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the $routeParams to have the locale as the first section:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/:local/home", { controller: "HOME_CONTROLLER" ... })
    .when("/:local/shop", { controller: "SHOP_CONTROLLER" ... })
```

Here's the documentation on it: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeParams)

Comment: I guess this will solve the first part. Thank you. But what about the base url being specified to `domain.com/#!/:locale/` for all links?

Comment: You're going to have to add that to each route when clause. Do you mean having each link in the system automatically set to #/:local/ ? i.e. href="#/:local/" ? If so just put the local on the $rootScope and reference it there like so: href="#/ROOT_SCOPE_LOCAL_VARIABLE"